# iMacros take screenshot of a dropdown box

Tags: javascript, imacros

I need to take a screenshot of the contents of a dropdown box on a webpage. Is there a way I can execute iMacros's SAVEAS command while a dropdown box is expanded? I tried doing a CLICK followed by a SAVEAS but that does not seem to work

Comment: Can you give us the website? Try using EVENT and after that CONTENT=EVENT:SAVE_ELEMENT_SCREENSHOT.

Comment: The site in question is access restricted but any dropdown box will do, an example available at http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms11.htm (select name="dropdownmenu"). How would I use the Event?

Comment: Use experimental recording.